# Find probability that the plane is launched within 10 minutes.

Tags: probability

a plane’s engines start successfully at a given attempt with a probability of 0.75. Any time that the mechanics are unsuccessful in starting the engines, they must wait five minutes before trying again. Find probability that the plane is launched within 10 minutes.

### try

Let $X$ be the number of times until place start succesfully. $X$ is geometric with parameter $p=0.75$. The plane is launched within $10$ minutes if we have try $3$ times thus

$$ P(X=3) = 0.25^2 \cdot 0.75 \approx 0.0469 $$

which does not coincide with answer in book which is $0.984375$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probability of 'launch' within 10mins is 1 - probability of no 'launch' = 1 - 0.25*0.25 = 0.9375

Comment: Intuitively, it should be clear to you that your answer is wrong.  The value you get for three tries is a lot less then the value for one try, which makes no sense.

Comment: The probability that starting fails three times in a row is $.25^3$ so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- your $P(X=3) = 0.25^2 \cdot 0.75 \approx 0.0469$ is the probability that the engines fail on the first two tries and succeed on the third try
- you should also consider $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$, since the question is in effect asking for $P(X \le 3)$
- an alternative approach would be to find $1-P(X>3)$, i.e. the probability that the starting process does not fail three times; this should give the same answer as directly calculating $P(X \le 3)$