# Calculate probability than more than three phone calls are required

Tags: probability

A representative of a market research firm contacts consumers by phone in order to conduct surveys. The specific consumer contacted by each phone call is randomly determined. The probability that a phone call produces a completed survey is 0.25. Calculate the probability that more than three phone calls are required to produce one completed survey.

#### Try

If I call $X$ to be the number of phones required until one completed survey (success in this case), then $X$ is geometric with $p=0.25$. Then we want $P(X>3)$ which is obviously

$$ P(X>3) = \sum_{x=3}^{\infty} 0.75^{x-1} 0.25 = \frac{0.25}{0.75} \sum_{x=3}^{\infty} 0.75^x = \frac{0.25}{0.75} \cdot (0.75)^3 \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} 0.75^x = 0.75^2\cdot0.25 \cdot \frac{1}{1-0.75} = 0.5625$$

Now, the answer key says it should $\boxed{0.42}$ but I am doing everything correct. IS it a typo in the answer key?

Comment: This is almost identical to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832997/find-probability-that-the-plane-is-launched-within-10-minutes).  The methods you were shown there will work here.

Comment: Note:  here your sum incorrectly includes the case where it takes exactly three calls.  As a general rule, though, falling back on infinite series tends to not be the best approach (as you have seen, that method is extremely error prone). Here, what you want is equivalent to saying the first three calls fail, so the answer is just $.75^3$

Comment: Note lulu comment.  $.5625=.75\times .5625=.421875$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches possible.

**1)** Your approach

$$ P(X>3) = \sum_{x=\color{red}4}^{\infty} 0.75^{x-1} 0.25 =\frac{0.25}{0.75}\cdot\sum_{x=\color{red}4}^{\infty} 0.75^{x}=\frac{0.25}{0.75}\cdot\left(\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}0.75^{x}-\sum_{x=1}^{3}0.75^{x}\right)  $$

$$\frac{0.25}{0.75}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1-0.75} -0.75\cdot\frac{1-0.75^3}{1-0.75} \right)= \frac{\require{cancel} \cancel{0.25}}{\require{cancel} \bcancel{0.75}}\cdot \left(\frac{\require{cancel} \bcancel{0.75}}{\require{cancel} \cancel{1-0.75}} -\require{cancel} \bcancel{0.75}\cdot\frac{1-0.75^3}{\require{cancel} \cancel{1-0.75}} \right)$$

$= \left(1- (1-0.75^3)\right)=0.75^3=0.421875\approx \boxed{0.42}$

**2)** Your approach, but applying converse probability

$$P(X>3)=1-P(X\leq 3)=1-\sum_{x=1}^{3} 0.75^{x-1} 0.25=1-0.25\cdot \sum_{x=1}^{3} 0.75^{x-1}$$

substitution: $y=x-1$

$$1-0.25\cdot \sum_{y=0}^{2} 0.75^{y}=1-\require{cancel} \cancel{0.25}\cdot \frac{1-0.75^3}{\require{cancel} \cancel{1-0.75}}=1- (1-0.75^3)=0.75^3$$

**3)** Just not completing the first three calls

We assume a constant probability $p$ to complete a survey.

$p=0.25\Rightarrow (1-p)=0.75$

The probability not completing the next three calls is $(1-p)^3=0.75^3$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=1/4$ be the probability of success. 
Let $q=3/4$ be the complementary probability. If we have success, we stop, else continue. Then the problem is modeled by the following tree:

```
  *p
 /
*    *p
 \  /
  *q    *p
    \  /
     *q
       \
        *q MORE THAN THREE...
```

The probability to land in `MORE THAN THREE...` is
$$q^3=\left(\frac 34\right)^3=\frac{27}{64}=0.421875\ .$$